# Powershell : The scope number '4' exceeds the number of active scopes

Tags: powershell

I keep hitting this error while calling functions from

I am not clear what this means, cause it is not consistent. I hit this very randomly, my ps session stops and I get error in automation.

Exception:

> The scope number '4' exceeds the number of active scopes.
>   Parameter name: scopeID
>   Actual value was 4.

Comment: Numbered Scopes:
        You can refer to scopes by name or by a number that
        describes the relative position of one scope to another.
        Scope 0 represents the current, or local, scope. Scope 1
        indicates the immediate parent scope. Scope 2 indicates the
        parent of the parent scope, and so on. Numbered scopes
        are useful if you have created many recursive
        scopes.

Comment: Look at the error message and find the line number. Inspect that line of your script and you should see a command with a -Scope argument. Remove or modify that line

Answer (score 2):

The error is pretty clear. It seems you are trying to get something from the  great-great-grandparent scope (parent of a parent of a parent of a parent scope). That scope does not exist hence the error. 4 is a valid value for scope but only if there if that scope actually exists.

If you look at [about_scopes](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh847849.aspx):

> Numbered Scopes:
>
> You can refer to scopes by name or by a number that
>           describes the relative position of one scope to another.
>           Scope 0 represents the current, or local, scope. Scope 1
>           indicates the immediate parent scope. **Scope 2 indicates the
>           parent of the parent scope, and so on**. Numbered scopes
>           are useful if you have created many recursive
>           scopes.

It would seem you are trying to call a variable, function, alias, cmdlet etc. by referring to its scope. The answer would lie in the code you are attempting.